# MapInfo auto-load switch off

Tags: mapinfo

In QGIS there is an option to switch off toggle rendering (the tick box is called Render), which makes it much quicker to zoom in and out on layers. Is there an equivalent option in MapInfo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open MapBasic Window (Options/Show MapBasic Window)
2. Type MapBasic command:

> `Set Map Redraw Suspended`

or

> `Set Map Redraw Off`

3. To turn it on again type:

> `Set Map Redraw On`

"Suspended" turns off the map display entirely.

Comment: Thanks, if this helps please upvote and accept the answer.